# Angularjs - save "clean" dom element content to server

Tags: angularjs, dom

I want to save an dom element (svg) of a angularjs driven webpage to the server. How can I get a string with the dom element content cleaned from all the angularjs specific attributes and also remove complete tags which are hidden via ng-hide ...

```
<g ng-hide="rootvm.artOnTop==true" class="ng-hide">
```

without actually changing the dom. I am new to angularjs...

thanks

martin

Comment: You can use `ng-if` for tag hiding.

Comment: thanks - the problem is that I want not to change the dom, i want a string with the svg content without the hidden stuff ...

Comment: oh I just realize that I can go the way you suggested, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<g ng-if="rootvm.artOnTop===true" class="ng-hide">
```